# What is server push and client push in gwt?

Tags: gwt

What is the server push,client push.What is the difference between server push and client push   and also server polling vs server pushing.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

These are all technologies for streaming data to the browser:

- server push is where you use a first-class streaming technology such as Server Sent Events, or WebSockets
- client push is not a real thing (to the best of my knowledge)
- server polling is where you are unable to use WebSockets, so the client code repeatedly polls the server for new data
- server pushing is the same as server push!

I'd recommend that you spent time reading about WebSockets and Comet.